# Is this solution classified as dynamic programming?

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

I have to prepare some examples of dynamic programming for my studies. Especially in optimalisation tasks. As first example I decided to write alghoritm to find the path from point (0,0) to point (n,m) on the (n,m)matrix such that the path sum would be the lowest. It seems to work fine but please ensure me if this alghoritm can be classified as dynamic programming. Could you please refer me to some implemented solutions of optimalization tasks using dynamic programming?

```
private static int[][] MATRIX = {
    {1,8,4,2},
    {1,1,4,2},
    {1,1,1,6}
};

for (int i = MATRIX.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = MATRIX[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            int temp;
            if (i + 1 < MATRIX.length && j + 1 < MATRIX[i].length)
                temp = Math.min(MATRIX[i + 1][j], MATRIX[i][j + 1]);
            else if (i + 1 < MATRIX.length)
                temp = MATRIX[i + 1][j];
            else if (j + 1 < MATRIX[i].length)
                temp = MATRIX[i][j + 1];
            else
                temp = 0;
                MATRIX[i][j] += temp;
         }
    }
    System.out.println(MATRIX[0][0]);
```

Comment: See "Intermediate" section here: http://help.topcoder.com/data-science/competing-in-algorithm-challenges/algorithm-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/  That's in pseudocode though, not C# or Java

Comment: Thanks. That's useful link